# How to change record type based on a criteria with Flow in Salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, process-automation

I used 'get Records' element to get record type id and then try to assign it to a record upon some criteria when contact created. I got the error as shown in bellow screenshot. can anyone highlight where the mistake is ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Flow is the recommendation for most new automation today.

Comment: Hard code ID and record types picklist, are not available. I tried on record create(Record-Triggered Flow) with variable but also not able to assign ID or type name to that. Hard code ID in process builder is also working but I want it in Flow.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask] and [help/on-topic], then [edit] your post to provide a complete description of what you've tried so far and what specific problem you are confronting.

Comment: @DavidReed, I update the details. Hope this will help more to understand.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more than one RecordType called "Finance"? You should probably add another filter to specify the SobjectType.

Comment: In general, we really need more details on what you've tried thus far.

Comment: Thanks for input @KevinO'Hara . I develop the solution which is in production now. :)